# Assignment Operation Value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="target"></div>

// JavaScript
function MyObject() {}

var $my_div = $('#target'),
    data;
$my_div.data('extra', (data = new MyObject()));
```

In JavaScript, the expression e.g. `(data = new MyObject())` evaluates to *MyObject* object; whereas, in a language like C, the value of an expression is always `true`.

In the code snippet above, is `(data = new MyObject())` only meant for a shortcut of doing exactly the same thing as the following?

```
...
var $my_div = $('#target'),
    data = new MyObject();
$my_div.data('extra', data);
```

**Clarifications**:
I initially wasn't sure what `(data = new MyObject())` actually does. I was wondering why not separating that expression in its own line, rather than doing it in `.data()`. The question was whether there were any differences between doing that expression in `.data()` or separately.

Comment: So what's the question? Yes that's how it works in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment operator in most languages actually evalutes to the value of assignment (=just like in JavaScript). For instance, it is common to see something like the below in C code:

```
MyObject* config = NULL;
if (config = parse_config()) {
   // config is not NULL
}
```

It is just a matter of how a particular language interprets something (e.g. If it treats non-NULL pointer as true). Some (like C# or Java) do not and require you to be specific, like:

```
MyObject config = null;
if ((config = ParseConfig() != null) {
   // config is not null
}
```

However, it doesn't seem as readable, so few people go with it.

As for your question, the examples do the same - no hidden magic found :)

Answer (score 7):

> In JavaScript, the expression e.g. `(data = new MyObject())` evaluates to `MyObject` object; whereas, in a language like C, the value of an expression is always `true`

No, in C just as in JavaScript, the result of the similar expression is a reference to the `MyObject` object. Non-`null` object references are truthy, though (in both languages).

In all of the languages syntactically derived from B (including C, Java, JavaScript, C#, and about a dozen more), and probably most languages from other families, the result of an *assignment expression* is the right-hand side of that expression. E.g.:

```
a = b = c;
```

...means "assign the value of `c` to `b`, then assign it again to `a` without re-evaluation". It does *not* mean "assign `c` to `b`, then assign `true` to `a`". I don't know of a language where it would mean that (which doesn't mean one doesn't exist). In some language families, it means "compare `b` to `c` and assign the result of that comparison to `a`" (without changing `b` or `c`), because `=` does double duty in those languages as both an assignment operator and as a comparison operator depending on context, and in that context (a *right-hand side* production), it's a comparison operator. (The BASIC languages are like that.)

This isn't really an *answer*, because there's no question. But hopefully it helps...